# How to calculate energy along a given direction in the Brillouin zone?

Tags: solid-state-physics

I am having trouble understanding how to calculate the energy dispersion relation $E(\vec{k})$ in a given direction within the first Brillouin zone.I can find the vectors in the reciprocal lattice. Any pointers?

Thank you

Comment: Did the answer helped or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly; you'll have to compute de value of $E(\mathbf{k})$ for a given vector composed of $k_{i}$ (i=x,y,z), as the result will be the energy and the $k_{i}$ the direction.

An example would be the square lattice of size $a\times a$ with a dispersion relation of $E(\mathbf{k}) = -\frac{E_{0}}{4} (\cos(k_{x}a) +\sin(k_{y} a))$ gives
[image: Dispersion relation of electrons of a square lattice]

Hope it helps, cheers